# How do I print the position of the mouse once it has been clicked, using opencv (python).

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Simply put, I want to continually check if the mouse has been clicked (lbutton).
I've been searching for awhile and I can't seem to find any good way to do so.

Comment: Have you checked this?
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/) they use the cv2 package and they set up a mouse callback to the window object by calling cv2.setMouseCallback:

```
import cv2
refPt = []

def function(event, x, y, flags, param):
  if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
    refPt = [(x, y)] 

..
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_and_crop)
```

See the link for more details. 
You might want to share a minimal example of your code so that people can better help you setting up the event handler for mouse events.